# Como esperar o termino de uma Thread e como receber valores dela?

Tags: vb.net, thread

Estou trabalhando numa situação, que requer o uso de multiprocessamento.

Preciso fazer leitura de arquivos e uma porrada de processos que podem tomar algum tempo. Durante este processo, quero exibir uma espécie de janela pro usuário `(Aguarde...)` sem comprometer a thread da UI e sem causar aquelas esbranquiçadas que ocorrem quando a interface grafica deixa de ser atualizada.

Entretando, fica dificil saber quando a thread terminou seu trabalho, pois o processo não tem tempo definido e pode variar de acordo com o volume de informações tratadas e da configuração da máquina. Fuçando na internet, eu achei o metodo join, responsável por aguardar o termino do processamento das threads. Entretanto eu sou obrigado a estipular um tempo pra que ele saia do modo de espera e como eu citei antes, o processo pode levar de pouco a muito tempo.

A minha *thread* executa um método que tem retorno e também não estou conseguindo recuperar a informação deste método. Pesquisei na internet, mas não ficou claro ainda. Não sei como recuperar os dados tratados pela *thread*.

Minha *thread* executa um método que captura informações do banco, compara com um arquivo texto e depois retorna um `ArrayList` com os dados discrepantes. O problema é preciso saber quando o processo terminou e receber o resultado deste método.

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim OPF As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim Caminho As String
    Dim Aviso As New frmWarning
    Dim ListaEntradas As ArrayList

    If IO.Directory.Exists(Path) Then
        Caminho = Path
    Else
        Caminho = Path.Substring(1, 3)
    End If

    With OPF
        .InitialDirectory = Caminho
        .ShowDialog()
    End With

    Aviso.Show()
    Dim compara As New Thread(AddressOf TDNFEntradas)
    compara.Start(OPF.FileName)

    'ListaEntradas = (E AGORA? COMO RECEBER A LISTA DA THREAD?)
    Aviso.Close()


End Sub

Private Function TDNFEntradas(ByVal Endereco As String) As ArrayList
    Dim NFentradas As New ArrayList
    Dim Mensagem As New frmWarning
    Dim Lista As New ArrayList

    HabilitarControlesNF(False) ' Desabilita controles do formulario
    NFentradas = CapturarNotas(Endereco, 0) ' Carrega Numeros das Notas dentro de um arrayList
    Lista = CompNotasEntrada(NFentradas) ' Compara dados da lista com o banco e retorna as diferenças numa outra lista
    HabilitarControlesNF(True) 'Habilita controles do formulario

    Return Lista 'Retorna lista com discrepancias

End Function
```

Comment: Você pode colocar exemplos de código da sua implementação de thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra obter o retorno de uma `Function` executada em *Thread*, você precisa usar um `BackgroundWorker`:

```vb
Private WithEvents BackgroundWorker1 As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
```

Seu código final vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```vb
Private Class Entradas
    Public CaminhoArquivo As String
    Function TDNFEntradas() As ArrayList
        Dim NFentradas As New ArrayList
        Dim Mensagem As New frmWarning
        Dim Lista As New ArrayList

        HabilitarControlesNF(False) ' Desabilita controles do formulario
        NFentradas = CapturarNotas(CaminhoArquivo, 0) ' Carrega Numeros das Notas dentro de um arrayList
        Lista = CompNotasEntrada(NFentradas) ' Compara dados da lista com o banco e retorna as diferenças numa outra lista
        HabilitarControlesNF(True) 'Habilita controles do formulario

        Return Lista 'Retorna lista com discrepancias

    End Function
End Class

Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim OPF As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim Caminho As String
    Dim Aviso As New frmWarning
    Dim ListaEntradas As ArrayList
    Dim ClasseEntradas As New Entradas

    If IO.Directory.Exists(Path) Then
        Caminho = Path
    Else
        Caminho = Path.Substring(1, 3)
    End If

    With OPF
        .InitialDirectory = Caminho
        .ShowDialog()
    End With

    Entradas.CaminhoArquivo = OPF.FileName
    Aviso.Show()

    ' Executar Thread com Worker
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(Entradas)
End Sub 

' Este é o método que realiza o trabalho em Thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(
    ByVal sender As Object, 
    ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs
    ) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim Entradas As ClasseEntradas = CType(e.Argument, Entradas)
    ' Retorne o valor por e.Result
    e.Result = Entradas.TDNFEntradas()
End Sub 

' Este método executa quando a Thread termina
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs
    ) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

    ' Obter Resultado
    Dim Lista As ArrayList = CDbl(e.Result)
    ' Trate aqui sua lista
End Sub
```

Basicamente eu adaptei este artigo aqui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkays279.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4

Comment: Eu cheguei ao mesmo artigo, entretanto... o problema é a conversao do resultado no final... nao encontro nenhuma maneira de converte-lo para lista.

Comment: Ali no método `BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted`. O valor não volta convertido? O que falta?

Comment: Ele é convertido para Double, certo? O.o' e a minha lista é um arraylist de strings...

Comment: Por que? `e.Result` é `Object`, não `Double`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.result(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: CDbl(e.Result) <-- entendeu? nessa parte rola uma conversao para double, entretanto eu preciso converte-lo para algum tipo de estrutura de tabela ou uma colecao(ArrayList).

Comment: Hmm... nao precisa de conversao, eu consegui jogar na lista direto. Grato!

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro Poderia por favor marcar a resposta como aceita, em benefício da comunidade? Obrigado!

Comment: Perdao, eu havia me esquecido :D muito grato